# Getting error while converting C MEX-file into pure c++

Tags: c, pointers, mex

i am converting some C mex-files into pure C++. obviously i need to convert mxarrays and mex  functions.

as you see in the [code](http://pastebin.com/sVvnU1tc), it creates an mxarray at line 60,

```
mxArray *mxGradient = mxCreateNumericArray(3, out, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
```

and at the line 61 assigns it to a pointer with mxgetpr,

```
double *gradient = (double *)mxGetPr(mxGradient);
```

at the line 68 it sums the pointer with multiplication of integers,

```
double *tempGradientVBase   = gradient + ( out[0] * out[1]);
```

i couldn't manage to understand the line 68. what does it means?

i don't know so much about mxarrays and mex files. could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [C pointer arithmetic](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10b.html).

The code that you pasted is treating `gradient` as a pointer to the first `double` in an array of `double`s. By `gradient + ( out[0] * out[1] )`, it means "give me the pointer to the `double` at index `out[0] * out[1]` in the array of `double`s beginning at `gradient`". It is equivalent to `&gradient[ out[0] * out[1] ]`.